# How to select database items recursively in C# using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, relationship

I have the following objects:

```
public class AccountDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(30), MinLength(6)]
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50), MinLength(6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? SecondaryPassword { get; set; }

    public SystemInformationDTO? SystemInformation { get; set; }
}

public class SystemInformationDTO
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Os { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Cpu { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string? Gpu { get; set; }
}
```

And the following context class:

```
public class AccountContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<AccountDTO>? Account { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SystemInformationDTO>? SystemInformation { get; set; }

    public AccountContext()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlServer("myConnectionString");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<AccountDTO>()
            .ToTable("Account", "Account");

        builder.Entity<AccountDTO>()
            .HasOne(x => x.SystemInformation);

        builder.Entity<SystemInformationDTO>()
            .ToTable("SystemInformation", "Account");
    }
}
```

With this, my database is generated as I wanted. I also populated properly.

Now, I have this repository using my context:

```
public class AccountQueriesRepository : IAccountQueriesRepository
{
    private readonly AccountContext _context;

    public AccountQueriesRepository(AccountContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public AccountDTO? GetAccountByUsername(string username)
    {
        return _context?.Account?
            .Include(x => x.SystemInformation)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Username == username);
    }

    public AccountDTO? GetAccountById(long id)
    {
        return _context?.Account?
            .Include(x => x.SystemInformation)
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    }
}
```

But when I call the `GetAccount` (by id or by username, whatever) it does not retrieve the `SystemInformation`.

How can I do it without creating separated "selects" in my context?

Thanks!

Edit:

[image: Database screenshot]

Comment: That all looks OK.  Turn on logging and validate that the queries are being generated as you expect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/simple-logging

Comment: Are you storing user passwords in plain text?

Comment: You will have to use an additional select... just create a DTO that has all the fields you need, perhaps use mapster(or automapper) to project to that DTO. Optionally you can try with.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Enabbling logs and sensitive data logging gave me some info. Now i have at least the related Id in my AccountDTO. Thanks.

Comment: @Aron Its encripted (for now im using base64 bcz my Blazor Pages doesnt accept Any System.Crptography).

Comment: @AMunim Thats bad.... but okay, thank you.

Comment: base64 isn't encryption any more than ROT13 is. Also, it sounds like your are pulling your entire user/password database down onto the browser, where the "decryption keys" also live.